# How to add a distinct value to repeating columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table with `CountryName` and an `id`.

Eg.

```
id   CountryName 
-----------------
1    Afghanistan
2    Afghanistan
3    Afghanistan 
4    Albania     
5    Albania     
6    Albania     
7    Albania
```

I want to add a new column `CountryID` where all the repeating `CountryName` will have a distinct `CountryID` like below.

Eg.

```
id   CountryName   CountryID
-----------------------------    
1    Afghanistan      1
2    Afghanistan      1
3    Afghanistan      1
4    Albania          2
5    Albania          2
6    Albania          2
7    Albania          2
```

I have many countries that keep repeating and I want to add a `CountryID` to them to make it easier to do joins. Is it possible to do it by a T-Sql script?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps another option using `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
Select id 
      ,CountryName
      ,CountryID  = dense_rank() over (order by CountryName)
From   YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

So, I understand that you want to add these CountryIDs into the table.
Hence, you would need an update statement to update the column CountryID.

Extending [John Cappelletti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52359580/3635529) about using Dence_Rank, I think the following update statement should work.

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.CountryID = t2.CountryID
    FROM [Your table] t1
    JOIN (Select id 
          ,CountryName
          ,CountryID  = dense_rank() over (order by CountryName)
    From   [Your table]) t2 ON t1.CountryName = t2.CountryName
```

Comment: Well done for adding the actual update.   Could also be done via a CTE  +1